# Exception raised by NSExpressionDescription with Core Data in-memory store

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7, nsfetchrequest

I use this NSExpressionDescription to get the max value for the attribute date_modified:

```
NSFetchRequest *dateModifiedFR = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"MyEntity"];
dateModifiedFR.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"date_modified"];
NSExpression *maxDateExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"max:" arguments:@[keyPathExpression]];

NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[expressionDescription setName:@"maxDate"];
[expressionDescription setExpression:maxDateExpression];
[expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSDateAttributeType];
dateModifiedFR.propertiesToFetch = @[expressionDescription];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *resultDictionaries = [moc executeFetchRequest:dateModifiedFR error:&error];
NSDate *maxDate = [[resultDictionaries firstObject] valueForKey:@"maxDate"];
```

This works fine under iOS 7 as long as I use a SQLite store. But now I want to run this code with my unit tests using an in-memory store and executing this fetch request throws: `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDate count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa01b410'`

I know that there are other ways to get the max value in this case, but I'm curious what's wrong with this fetch request or why it can't run on the in-memory store.

Comment: I could reproduce the problem, and it looks like a Core Data bug to me.

Comment: I may mistake.. `[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.date_modified"];` instead of `[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"date_modified"];`

Comment: @Petro: Unfortunately, `unionOfObjects` raises an exception `[<NSDictionaryMapNode 0xa1253e0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key unionOfObjects.` I'm also pretty sure that the syntax is correct because I took most of it from the Apple docs and it runs fine with the SQLite store.

Comment: I may mistake again.. `@unionOfObjects`, not just `unionOfObjects`. At sign is important here. Your exception tells me that you have missed `@` sign inside key path

Comment: Right, I missed the @. The result is the same though: `...class is not key value coding-compliant for the key @unionOfObjects.'` With a SQLite store I get a different exception: `uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid keypath element (not a relationship or attribute): @unionOfObjects'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is actually a bug. I've filed a radar with Apple.

Comment: The same if sum (and probably any other aggregate function) is used. Filled radar as well: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5287242985635840