# NSPredicate: Getting the highest value

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

I've got the following:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedObjContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "RAS")
    var error: NSError?
    let predicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "%K AND %K == false",  "rasScore", "rasStatus")

    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate1

    do {...
```

This gives me ALL the records that conform to the parameters of the NSPredicate, but I want ONLY the record with the highest value in `rasScore`.  How do I go about getting that?  Is it possible to include that in the NSPredicate format?

Comment: You want all the record but values from highest to lowest. ? It means rasScore having a highest value, that particular record will be first and having a lowest value will be last

Comment: set the sort and limit to 1 result you mean?

Comment: That's what, he can set the sort using NSSortDescriptor and limit using setFetchLimit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Core Data - How to fetch an entity with max value property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398019/core-data-how-to-fetch-an-entity-with-max-value-property)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the `fetchLimit` of your `fetchRequest` to 1 and use a descriptor to sort by value of `"rasScore"` descending like this:

```
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
var highestSortDescriptor : NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "rasScore", ascending: false)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [highestSortDescriptor]
```

Comment: Thanks a million, @MarkHim!  I wasn't aware of the existence of fetchLimit.